# How to handle null values when a method doesn't return an Option?

Tags: java, scala, null

What is the correct way to handle the below case with null values in Scala? The `getField()` and `generateMetric()` method return a String. If it returned an Option I could probably apply pattern match here.

In `Java` I usually made it like this:

```
String metric_1 = null;
String metric_2 = null;

if (myObject.getField() != null) {
    metric_1 = myObject.getField();
} else {
    metric_2 = generateMetric();
}
```

Comment: Also note that using `;` is not idiomatic in Scala code style (as usually useless)

Comment: @cchantep the code example that I've provided is Java code hence the `;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values that can be `null` you wrap in an `Option`, like:

```
val isNull = null
val isNotNull = "hello"

println(Option(isNull)) // None

println(Option(isNotNull)) // Some(hello)
```

Check out this article: [NO NULL VALUES](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/no-null-values.html)

Your example could look like:

```
val metric = 
  Option(myObject.getField()).getOrElse(generateMetric())
```

1. Wrap the method that can return `null`.
2. Return it if there is a value, or generate the metric if it is `null`.

Comment: Yes, I know that it's possible to wrap the values into Option. But how would it look like for my above example?

Comment: Thanks! I've also tried this: `val metric_1 = Option(myObject.getField()) val result = metric_1 match {
        case Some(metric) => metric
        case None => generateMetric()
      }` But your approach with `getOrElse` looks better